# Can I move a Transporter directly inside a Cell in a storage Block?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I used the MoveByTransporter block of the Material handling Library. My goal is that I have a bucket (Agent) at a "Beginning Node" and it gets Transportet by an AGV inside a Storage Cell. I realised that when I let the Model run, the bucket gets Transportet to the upper Corner of the Storage(Node) and after that inside a Free Cell of the Storage.
The moveByTransporter Block has the Option to set a Destination. I thought about setting the destination to (x, y, z) and set for example the x-coordinate to Storage.getFreeCell().getX() something like that. But I have no idea if that works.
Does somebody have an Idea how I can Transport an Agent (Bucket) directly inside a Cell of a Storge by a AGV?

I tried to set the Destination of the AGV to (x, y, z) coordinates to a free Cell of the Storage like x = Storage.getFreeCell().getX()